# SVG objects are initially loaded vertically and then re-arranged horizontally in browser

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a bunch of SVGs that are supposed to sit next to each other horizontally.

**html code:**

```
<svg height="70" width="70" style="position:relative; z-index: 1; margin: -18px;">
  <circle cx="35" cy="35" r="28" stroke="grey" stroke-width="8" fill="none"  />
  <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" stroke="grey" stroke-width="2px" dy=".3em">T</text>
</svg>

<object data="imgs/su.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <img src="imgs/su.svg" />
</object>

<svg height="70" width="70" style="position: relative; z-index: 0; margin: -18px;">
  <circle cx="35" cy="35" r="28" stroke="grey" stroke-width="8" fill="none"  />
  <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" stroke="grey" stroke-width="2px" dy=".3em">T</text>
</svg>
.
.
.
```

My browser is chrome and what ends up happening is that chrome loads each one in its own "block" thus causing a line break and once all items are loaded then re-arranges them horizontally.

This issue takes upto **2 seconds** to get resolved on smartphone which is a bit ugly. Any solutions?

Comment: @Paulie_D You can reproduce this with the same code pasted in the question. It needs an external svg file which can't be attached to code snippets. Btw did you vote my question to be closed?

Comment: You do not need an `<object>` to wrap your SVG image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've commented before, geet rid of `<object>` wrapping your svg image as unnecessary, and you'll be OK:

```html
<svg height="70" width="70" style="position:relative; z-index: 1; margin: -18px;">
  <circle cx="35" cy="35" r="28" stroke="grey" stroke-width="8" fill="none"  />
  <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" stroke="grey" stroke-width="2px" dy=".3em">T</text>
</svg>

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Firefox_Logo%2C_2017.svg" width="70" height="70" style="position: relative; z-index: 0; margin: -18px;" />

<svg height="70" width="70" style="position: relative; z-index: 0; margin: -18px;">
  <circle cx="35" cy="35" r="28" stroke="grey" stroke-width="8" fill="none"  />
  <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" stroke="grey" stroke-width="2px" dy=".3em">T</text>
</svg>
```